# Error in nvidia-331 causes me unable to install, delete, or do almost anything besides open up a browser

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dpkg

I have Ubuntu 14.10 I cannot purge, or reinstall nvidia-331 and this seems to be destroying my computer. This is what happens when I put in `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331`

```
Removing nvidia-331 (331.113-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1) ...stop: Unknown instance: 
userdel: user nvidia-persistenced is currently used by process 1486
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-331 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 8
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-331
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
```

Also I can not change drivers and when I try there is no error message it just sends me back to the old driver like I did not try to change the drivers.

Comment: Have you tried changing the drivers through the Ubuntu GUI?

Comment: Yes that's the only thing I have currently done to change the drivers

Answer (score 0):

You must try change the graphics drivers through the Ubuntu CLI.

`Switch on` your computer.

Press and hold the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`.

Your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

Select the line ending with `Drop to root shell prompt`. *(netroot) or (network) - (root)*

Run in the terminal:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Now run:

```
apt-get purge nvidia*
apt-get install nvidia-331
```

Comment: would this work for my last question as well? the very first step ( 0) ) from the solution proposed in the only answer posted to my question fails with a similar error as reported here! the only difference is that I don't get the phrase ```Unknown instance: userdel: user nvidia-persistenced is currently used by process 1486``` in my error: ```https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04``` thank you!