# My nVidia drivers wont update in Ubuntu 20.04.3. How can I fix this? (I will put the screenshot in the description)

Tags: updates

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a Dell XPS M1730. It works, its really good. But the problem is that whatever video I try to play (local or on the internet) it lags real hard.

I can hear the sound, but the video lags. My current nVidia driver is the 8800GTX. I thought the driver wasn't updated so I tried to update it. I keep getting this message:

[image: Screensjot]

If its not a driver problem, please let me know.

Also if you know why the video lags, please let me know (it's not the internet problem).

Comment: The driver version seems correct - 340 - but... It isn't available in the official Ubuntu repositories. Have you added a PPA? If so please edit the question and post the exact instructions you followed. Meanwhile make sure the system is fully updated: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. If any errors make sure to include the full error messages in you edit.

Comment: I'd suggest you should be trying to install  the nvidia 390 driver. The default "nouveau" will get you nowhere - drivers below 390 are not supported by Ubuntu and should not be used . Mind that the NVIDIA driver needs to be supported by the linux kernel...

Comment: @kanehekili v. 390 does not support this old card, it'll be worse than using nouveau (and not even offered in Additional drivers for that reason). Nvidia says the latest version with support for this ancient hardware is indeed the LTS branch 340 that can still be installed thanks to an *ad hoc* PPA to extend support for legacy hardware, hence my question above.

Comment: I very much appreciate your attitude - I'm a fan of old hardware. But the driver needs to be compiled against the current kernel. If the ppa is no a dedicated to the "Focal Fossa" repo, it will not work. If it has "Bionic Beaver" in its name, you should not use it.

Comment: So there is no way?

Comment: So... My boot menu isnt showing up

Comment: See my answer - but I can't guarantee it'll work. I've seen much degradation  on my old Thinkpad laptops, which used to run perfectly on Linux 10 years ago ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting this question - since the OP tries to run his old hardware on a current Linux I'd like to mention that an old NVIDIA driver (which needs to be used by that hardware) does not necessarily work with the actual kernel. The question has been asked and answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04) already and should be taken into consideration.

You need to remove the "modern" 5.11 kernel and install the 5.4 kernel in order to get it to work.

Comment: I am really sorry to to bother you like this, but can you please tell me step by step on how to do it?

Comment: "RTFM" - the link should describe what you are supposed to do- your question has been asked already - and answered

Comment: I read the question, i did the steps, but at the reboot and open grub boot menu, i went to hard drive, but it just shows me the ubuntu logo and boots the normal way. I am using a Dell XPS M1730, if that helps.

Comment: it works! Anyone having trouble click on this link and scroll down and follow instructions.

Comment: oops here is the link

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: if my answer helped, you should accept it