# nvidia-340 driver on Ubuntu 20.04 getting error

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, linux-headers

[image]

I try to solve these links but had no luck
[nvidia-340 driver on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04)

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to first list all current diversions for the `libGL.so.1` file like this:

```
dpkg-divert --list | grep libGL.so.1
```

If you have a record, then you can rename the offending file:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

From here, you can attempt the installation one more time.