# Browsers unable to save downloads to network drive after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: files, 22.04, nas

I did a clean install, replacing Ubuntu 20.04 with 22.04. Since then the web browsers (both Chrome & Firefox) cannot save any downloaded files  to my network drive (a QNAP NAS). The browsers can "see" the NAS and even let me pick the save destination. But the files just refuse to be downloaded and saved on the NAS. Saving the files to local disk is OK. Anyone having the same problem? Help needed.

Comment: Are these snap packages or debs? ...Could be related to some snap containment issues that seem to appear in 22.04

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Firefox is the version that comes with 22.04. I believe it's snap. For Chrome, I installed it using Google's deb.

Comment: I wanted to blame snap/apparmor confinement on everything, but perhaps it is not that (or just that) if chrome is a regular deb package. (It could still be affected by some misconfigured apparmor profile though). Could it be that somehow the read/write privileges on your network drive are not set up correctly for the account/group that your browsers are running from? Have you tried starting the browsers from a shell -- there could be some diagnostic messages revealing the root of the issue

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767316 Both Chrome (.deb) and the default Firefox that is installed with 22.04 (snap) use the same file picker and experience the same symptom: can navigate a network share and select a file, but cannot save or open a share file; they fail silently with no error shown.

Comment: Exactly! No error message at all. Just nothing happens and no files saved to the network drive.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me
https://askubuntu.com/a/1406495

the solution consist in install a gnome package

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

after restart it worked!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue. Just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. I cannot attach files (in Gmail) from a remote network share (mounted by gvfs over ssh). I can browse and select the File from the "Open Files" dialog, but it doesn't attach. I don't get an error message, either. It just doesn't attach the file. On the other hand, if I manually mount the share (using FUSE) in my home directory, it works.

Comment: I just upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04, and now Chrome (deb), Thunderbird (snap), and FireFox (snap) will not open nor save to any network drives (a home Ubuntu server); all of these apps read/saved to the same server before the upgrade this afternoon.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767316

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the gnome package above and it already stated that I had the latest version.

You can still access the mount, however, you need to know where the mount point is on your local machine. You can see an example of how to do this in a response on [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1773624).

TL;DR; You should be able to access it via *Other Locations* -> Computer -> run/user/user_id/gvfs as stated in the link above. HTH