# unable to add attachment (from remote location) to an email in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, email, remote, attachment

Yesterday I upgraded my ubuntu to 22.04.1 LTS. And when I was sending an email, I was not able to add an attachment which was from remote server location. Only attachments from local machine could be added. This was not an issue before. For instance, I opened chrome-gmail -add attachment- click on the file I want to attach- but then nothing happens and the cursor return to my email. Nothing freezes but it doesnot attach either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I fixed it now. The problem is with gmail and our university email while adding attachment from browser - both firefox and chrome. These applications have the access to remote locations and worked fine until the upgrade. And it is quite important to me as most of the work in on servers.

Comment: Could you please add some details regarding the remote location? What kind of connection is made? Are you able to copy the file to your computer?

Comment: Remote locations are network location that I access via ssh or connect to server on the Files in ubuntu. I am unable to upload from these say to any email attachment or download anything to the remote location. Both upload and download are working fine from local computer. So I have to first transfer the file from remote to local computer and then attach to email for example. Are there any solutions to this? Thanks

Comment: Any ideas? The problem is same as in this question too https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405148/browsers-unable-to-save-downloads-to-network-drive-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04