# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and elitebook 8440P hangs roughly within minute of login

Tags: laptop, hp, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and elitebook 8440P hangs roughly within minute of login.

I have old elitebook 8440P(8gb memory and 120gb ssd). After installing any of the 22.04 LTS flavors (Ubuntu, MATE, Kubuntu) install goes ok. But after reboot and login its hangs within minute or two within login.

I've already run a memtest and full PC-check 8 test suite on computer and everything is OK.
Also older versions of Ubuntu(or mint) work fine (I've been using 21.10 until recently).

Also how should I start figuring out whats going on, becaus it a total hang only way is powerbutton.

any good ideas and workarounds are  welcome.

--MP

Comment: As with all troubleshooting efforts, start with the contents of `/var/log`, particularly `syslog`. This is where your system will try to report problems.

Comment: I also search for a solution.
I have the same issue but with a HP 8510W Laptop & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I guess it is related with the Nvidia graphics adapter. Mark

Comment: The exact thing happens on my MSI GL63 8RC. Ctrl Alt F1 does nothing, only holding the power button allows me to shut the machine down. I haven't installed the nvidia drivers, it was only running on integrated graphics. The only change I've made to the machine, is that I've put in a Samsung 970 EVO Plus.

Comment: I think the problem is poor cooperation between 22.04 and nvidia graphics when running Wayland. Different versions of nvidia graphics chips may have different problems. I switched to Xorg in my computer with nvidia, and the problem was solved. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857) that shows an easy way to switch to Xorg.

Answer (score 2):

I got it running!

source: [nvidia-340 driver on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Try:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install nvidia-340

sudo apt install xorg-modulepath-fix

it worked with my HP 8510w and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After trawling thru here and couple other places. I've come into conclusion that this problem stems from the fact that all the machines are usually first gen core processors or older. (in my case Core i5-650 Thinkserver and core i5-520m Elitebook).

--MP