# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: Starting firefox through terminal Error "cannot change mount " & Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module", How to solve it?

Tags: command-line, unity, firefox, 22.04

System information:
[Computer Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl8fH.png)

```
Ubuntu version: 
philossefer@dell:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

When I'm trying to launch Firefox Web Browser through terminal, following message is displayed before firefox is launched.

```
philossefer@dell:~$ firefox
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/libreoffice/help /usr/share/libreoffice/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create directory "/usr/share/libreoffice/help": permission denied
Gtk-Message: 11:19:46.906: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 11:19:46.985: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

Afterwards, whenever I'm trying to launch firefox, after the first launch in-between system boot, following messaged is been displayed before firefox gets launched.

```
philossefer@dell:~$ firefox
Gtk-Message: 11:19:46.906: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 11:19:46.985: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

I have tried the following solution,by "copy and paste" those messages on google.

[What I have tried so far, without any success](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)

Try 1

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Try 2

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Try 3: Remove firefox and then reinstall

Uninstall:

```
 sudo snap remove firefox
```

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

NOTE: I was rebooting the system after, every installation and uninstallation.

```
reboot
```

Also Updated my Ubuntu beforehand.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

**Current Status:** Still those messages are there, when I'm launching firefox using command line.

My question is, why those messages are been displayed and how to get rid of them?

*SubQuestion*: Is there any difference between launching firefox through icon and through using command line?

Comment: **If your Firefox is working correctly, you can ignore the messages to the terminal window.** Many graphical programs send warning messages when started from a terminal window. -- Otherwise, if Firefox fails, and if you are using Wayland, you can try after changing to Xorg for the desktop graphics. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857) to another (maybe similar) thread at AskUbuntu.

Comment: That is 'only' a comment, not an error message.

Comment: @sudodus
This is fresh installed copy of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,
On booting with ext4 or LVM installed copy, It would display 
`/dev/sda2: clean, 194908/6102208 files, 6378606/244059136 blocks`
before the login.

Installing Ubuntu through ZFS helped to resolve that issue.

While trying to resolve 
`/dev/sda2: clean, 194908/6102208 files, 6378606/244059136 blocks`

I tried, 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-vesa`
`Xorg -configure'
`startx`

From [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857)

Comment: @sudodus Here, again you're suggesting _Otherwise, if Firefox fails, and if you are using Wayland, you can try after changing to *Xorg* for the desktop graphics._

IS there a correlation between it? Installation booting comment and firefox comment?

Comment: In this case, I don't think so. Do Firefox and other important programs work?

Comment: So far  have used firefox and GIMP. it's working fine. No comments are displayed for GIMP while running it through command line.

Comment: Many graphical programs send warning messages when started from a terminal window. I am used and don't worry about it as long as the programs work as they should. I think it is simply things that the developers forgot to clean because those messages will not show, when called from a menu or similar (in the graphical desktop environment).

Comment: I did check the link you provided, _Method to switch from Wayland to X (to make Firefox work)_. In the file, it is already false `#WaylandEnable=false`. Thought the comments were some error as no comment are shown for GIMP and many other. So tried to resolve it. Thank you @sudodus for sharing your time and knowledge. Moving forward for now.

Comment: The `#` character makes it a comment, not active. You must remove the `#` character from that line in order to make it active. So I think you run Wayland. Anyway, if Firefox works (and you have no other problem due to Wayland, you can continue without changing from Wayland to Xorg). Wayland is more modern. Good luck with your Ubuntu 22.04 LTS :-)

Comment: @sudodus My bad, i didn't read your [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857) properly, the first time. I did uncomment it, saved the file and reboot the system, but still it didn't solved the issue. So, I undo the whole Wayland thing. As my Firefox is working fine and no real issue is there, which one should I prefer between _launching Firefox through command line_ or _launching it through GUI (by clicking Firefox icon)_?  Which one will be good for the system performance?

Comment: Both will work well. So you decide what you like better. If you put Firefox into background with `nohup firefox &`, the terminal window can be used for other tasks and the cruft will be written to the file `nohup.out`. And if you want to open a particular web site, you can add it as parameter on the command line in a terminal window. But on the other hand, it is convenient to only click on an icon.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I was not able to get the snap working, however I was able to successfully install a Firefox deb on Ubuntu 22.04. You add the Mozilla Team PPA, install the Firefox deb, then pin them so the Firefox Snap is not installed later. Here are the steps I followed:

Step 1:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Step 2:

```
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

Step 3:

```
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

Step 4:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Reference: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Had a similar problem with inkscape 1.2 on ubuntu 22.04.some functionalitiese weren't working correctly. When starting from terminal, the failed-to-load-"canberra-gtk-module" message appeared. Uninstalling the snap-package and installing via apt fixed the problem

Comment: 2024 the snap package is still not a good one (at least not in all cases). Switching to deb fixed firefox 123.0.1 for me. Firefox now survives a reboot. By the way appamor profiles for snap firefox 123.0.1 do have syntax errors (appamor_parser 3.0.4 says). Funny thing is that the snap packages works as long as i do not do a reboot. Use the link above to use the latest tutorial instructions!

Answer (score 1):

Can't upvote or comment on the second answer due to just creating an account for mainly that purpose - so I'll write a follow-up answer.

I've run into the same problem, force-installing the snap-package despite the normal use of apt by Ubuntu is causing a heap of issues, and the one you're observing is one of them.

Uninstall the snap package, install the apt-package as described by @kaiyobi, and your issues should be gone (just until Ubuntu force-feeds you the snap package again, ignoring Pin-Priority etc, by their installers).

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure it start well in GUI (normally by *click*)

If yes, then Try:

`$ firefox-esr` (this may work)

[image: Firefox logo]

Comment: It's working fine in GUI as well as through command line. I tried `firefox-esr` and this is the output `firefox-esr: command not found`.

Comment: I think u install with snap

Comment: I think u install with snap <br> that why msg occured . something snap not work fine. May be, snap can't get resources install by "apt'' . For example.., If u install VLC Media Player with apt as well snap .... You find there are two vlc media player available in menu.... you """"FireFox""" snap and you install PacKage 
 through apt ................. then remove the snap package (of firefox) and install through apt *****It work well***       thank

Comment: Earlier it was installed via apt, found it using `type firefox`. I removed it, due to your second comment _I think u install with snap_ and installed it via snap. Later I read your recent comment, so should I install **firefox** or **firefox-esr** via **apt**?