# Launching kmymoney through command line:Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway

Tags: command-line, 22.04, wayland, kmymoney

I have just installed kmymoney on ubuntu 220.4 LTS thourgh following command line
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y kmymoney
reboot

After reboot, when I tried to launch it through command line, following error message is displayed before it got launched.

```
philossepher@dell:~$ kmymoney
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
WebConnect: Try to connect to WebConnect server
WebConnect: Connect to server failed
WebConnect: Running in server mode
System icon theme as reported by QT:  "Yaru"
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
Icon theme "breeze" not found.
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_reportsview.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/icalendarexporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/reconciliationreport.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/konlinetasks_sepa.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/csvexporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/onlinejoboutboxview.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kbanking.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_checkprinting.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_csvimporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/sqlstorage.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/qifexporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_icalendarexporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/csvimporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/forecastview.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_forecastview.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_xmlstorage.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/checkprinting.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kcm_qif.so" Validity false
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/gncimporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/reportsview.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/budgetview.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/xmlstorage.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/qifimporter.so" Validity true
Located plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/ofximporter.so" Validity true
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/budgetview.so"
Plugins: budgetview loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/checkprinting.so"
Plugins: checkprinting loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/csvexporter.so"
Plugins: csvexporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/csvimporter.so"
Plugins: csvimporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/forecastview.so"
Plugins: forecastview loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/gncimporter.so"
Plugins: gncimporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/icalendarexporter.so"
Plugins: icalendarexporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/kbanking.so"
"Plugins: kbanking loaded, build with (5.9.0stable-0/6.4.3.0beta), run with (5.9.0.0/6.4.3.0)"
3:2022/05/21 10-39-38:(null)(5764):banking_update.c:  610: No AqBanking config folder found at [/home/philossepher/.aqbanking/settings6/users] (-1)
3:2022/05/21 10-39-38:(null)(5764):banking_update.c:  610: No AqBanking config folder found at [/home/philossepher/.aqbanking/settings/users] (-1)
3:2022/05/21 10-39-38:(null)(5764):banking_update.c:  411: There is no old settings folder, need initial setup
7:2022-05-21 10:39:38:aqbanking started
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/ofximporter.so"
Plugins: ofximporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/onlinejoboutboxview.so"
Plugins: onlinejoboutboxview loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/qifexporter.so"
Plugins: qifexporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/qifimporter.so"
Plugins: qifimporter loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/reconciliationreport.so"
Plugins: reconciliation report loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/reportsview.so"
Plugins: reportsview loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/sqlstorage.so"
Plugins: sqlstorage loaded
Loading "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kmymoney/xmlstorage.so"
Plugins: xmlstorage loaded
```

I think it got something to do with Wayland setting due to the following error message

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
```

As earlier while configuring my Firefox setting ([Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: Starting firefox through terminal Error "cannot change mount " & Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module", How to solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409575/ubuntu-22-04-lts-starting-firefox-through-terminal-error-cannot-change-mount?)) while trying different solutions I did edited my Wayland setting ([Ubuntu 22.04 Fresh installation Firefox will no load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857)), but later undo it.

**My question** is why I'm getting the error message when trying to run kmymoney through command line? *Though it starts after that error message and also starts through GUI (Clicking kmymoney icon).*

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
```