# How to change the position of the terminal window in Ubuntu 22.04 - gnome-terminal --geometryCxR+X+Y does not work

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Since I got Ubuntu 22.04 a few months ago, I wanted to know about how to specifically place different terminal windows in specific places on my second screen... until, eventually, I found the `--zoom` and `--geometry` options that allowed to do exactly what I required, e.g. like this: `gnome-terminal --zoom=1.2 --geometry=94x23+965+60`.
So, I created a little script to run at startup and everything worked fine... until about 3 weeks ago when I suddenly turned on the laptop, and out of the four terminal windows that were perfectly positioned before, three of them were overlapping. It was here where after googling about it, I found out that in Wayland this was never supposed to work!... however for more than a month (almost 5 weeks) it worked! and it worked perfectly! I don't understand what could have happened, first for everything to work very well, and then for it to suddenly stop working.
Now, as several people on the web comment, it really seems that the last part of the `--geometry` option, the one that refers to the window position, `+x+y`, is not recognized and is overwritten with the default option found in the terminal preferences.

Please, if anyone knows of a way in which that option could work again (or explain what might have happened in order to, perhaps, reverse it) or some other way in which I can make 4 of my terminal windows to be in positions of my preference, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The option `--geometry=CxR+X+Y` works for me in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but I should also mention that I am running in Xorg, not Wayland, because there are also other things, that don't work with Wayland. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857), which describes how to switch to Xorg.

Comment: Thanks, @sudodus, yes I had read that it doesn't happen in Xorg, however, I don't know the pros and cons of switching from Wayland to Xorg .... Since you use Xorg, do you know if there is any disadvantage of using Xorg over Wayland? (I'm seriously considering switching) ... or in any case, maybe you know why Ubuntu prefers Wayland by default? I find it strange, as after looking at your post, there are indeed other issues with Wayland.

Comment: Wayland is the future, Xorg is old and patched a million times, so I guess difficult to maintain, difficult to keep safe against attacks and slow. Wayland is a great step forward, or should I say, will be, because it is not quite ready yet. There are so many things, that must work, and we are not quite there yet. But if [most of] the things you need work in Wayland, do use it, and please write bug reports to Launchpad, when you find something that does not work, so that the developers will notice it and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Xterm does use the full geometry argument.
sudo apt install xterm