# How to start a X11 session

Tags: command-line

I get this message when starting SimpleScreenRecorder after upgrade to .04

> You are using a non-X11 window system (e.g. Wayland) which is
> currently not supported by SimpleScreenRecorder. Several features will
> most likely not work properly. In order to solve this, you should log
> out, choose a X11/Xorg session at the login screen, and then log back
> in.

Could someone give the exact command I can paste into the terminal. I am a total noob on this stuff.

Comment: There is no exact command to give. The instructions are clear: log out of your desktop session. Before you log in, find the cog wheel symbol on the login screen, and change the session type to something with "X" (i.e., not Wayland) in it. Then log in again. The screen recorder now should work.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running (for example 20.04.4 LTS or 22.04.1 LTS? The advice how to find the easiest method differs between versions.

Comment: the "cog wheel" may not be visible until you move your mouse to the lower-right area of the login screen

Comment: ... or not visible at all like in my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS. Then you can do it according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857).

Comment: I have  20.04.4 LTS. I am like a 5 year old on this stuff so humor me. I got the the edit part editing the #, but I don't know how to save it.

Comment: If you are running a current version of Ubuntu you probably have the **text mode editor `nano`**. Run it with elevated privileges: `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`; in that case you can **save the file and exit via the key combo `ctrl` + `x` (first press ctrl and keep it down while pressing x) and then answer `y` (yes)** or a corresponding letter for your local language. After that the edit should be saved. You can check it by looking at the file again (with `nano` and exit with `ctrl` + `x` (when no edit, nothing will be written and you need not answer `y`).

Answer (score 0):

As the message said, you have to enable a Window Manager which is compatible with that utility.  To do so, you need to go to "Control Center" then "MATE Tweak" (or GNOME Tweak) which will show something like the following:

[image]

Default for Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (My Desktop) is Marco.  You would need to select from that drop-down for a compatible WM.

"vi" is the default editor for most Unix/Linux OSs.  It would be very helpful for you to keep a "Vi cheetsheet" handy.  The following are just a few to pick from:

https://www.atmos.albany.edu/daes/atmclasses/atm350/vi_cheat_sheet.pdf

http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif

https://external-preview.redd.it/iigrixvxp5aYN9ox7Gr1dfI_rhLRotWlLsCafjJqjEQ.png?auto=webp&s=1594ddc17408cb9186a73c2a6d1a1bf1e00769dd

https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/52dc7b32-ee7c-491a-ac49-12779ff663be/vi-help-sheet-01-large2.jpg

If you haven't done so yet, I would suggest checking out any guidance provided by the original coder's project site:

```
https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr
```

If you are working with a version that is delivered with the OS distro, you might consider installing directly from the coder. It may have added logic and fixes that could address your issues in general, but not specifically for the fact that you Desktop may not be X-Windows based, for which it was designed.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand 90% of what you said. I just reverted to 16 to do the simple things I need done.

Comment: Wayland and X-Windows are two different graphics display rendering engines.  Wayland is newer, X-Windows is older, but not quite classified as legacy, because some systems, such as XFCE used as desktop manage for Xubuntu, continue the performance development of the X-Windows system.  You might want to try installing and using XFCE as an alternate desktop on Ubuntu 16 (you can have more than one desktop to choose at login, and try that out.  That way, you don't have to forgo the more modern tools that complement the later OSs.

Comment: Vi is a very powerful editor.  I've been using it now for 38 years.  I only use a small fraction of its capabilities to meet most of my needs: insert, delete, copy, paste;  single-character, word, line or multi-line operations; search and replace; import a text file.  Vi can do so much more.  Colour-highlighting for syntax of different languages, based on recognition of the #!/bin/{LANG} at the top of a script.

Comment: https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr  is the website for the project and source code for Simple Screen Recorder.  There is some documentation there that might be helpful, and they should be able to answer your troubleshooting questions, if you're not getting the answers you need here.

Comment: Ubuntu "manages" the versions of different software that it includes in a Distro.  They don't always use the latest (often better) versions that the developers offer, only on the basis of deploying a set of applications that they have verified all work for the distro.  Nobody likes having a broken tool amongst all the new stuff.  But for the most part, those developer versions are available in later verified versions, as well as later test/alpha/beta versions which for most users should be avoided.

Comment: When looking for information on Window Managers, avoid confusing that with Display Managers (https://vitux.com/some-common-ubuntu-display-managers-and-how-to-switch-between-them/).  To verify if your Windo Manager is Wayland, follow this guide:  https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/ .  You would then work thru the options available to you in the Control Panel, to then select a non-Wayland window manager.