# How to permanetely disable Wayland

Tags: wayland

I know I can stop using Wayland if I log out and change the setting, but I don't want to keep having to log out each time Ubunutu updates. Every time Ubuntu gets updated it enables Wayland again. I want to permenetly disable Wayland so it will never be used on my computer.

Comment: Curious as to why?  Personally I know X inside out and know nearly nothing about Wayland.  I don't know Wayland well enough to know why I would want to get rid of it?

Comment: @SwissFrank VM Ware Horizon Client is not compatible with Wayland.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I selected Xorg instead of Wayland according to the following link in my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS (now automatically 22.04.1 LTS).

[Method to switch from Wayland to X (to make Firefox work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857)

> Edit the configuration file,
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
> ```
>
> to uncomment [remove **`#`** from] the line containing
>
> ```
> WaylandEnable=false
> ```
>
> save the file (**<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>** and after that <kbd>y</kbd> ('yes') or another key for non-English and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and reboot.

This system has been updated & upgraded several times and it is still using Xorg.

Comment: Personally I know X inside out and know nearly nothing about Wayland.  I don't know Wayland well enough to know why I would want to get rid of it?

Comment: @SwissFrank, If Wayland works well for you with the tools that you use, fine, continue using it :-) But there are several tools/commands that do not work well or not at all with Wayland, and if you need such tools, you had better roll back to the classic Xorg. - Wayland is the new tool, and I think it will gradually replace Xorg, but the world of graphical tools is huge, and some tools were made to use Xorg in ways, that are not supported by Wayland, and it takes time to fix all problems. I think we need some modifications both in the tools and in Wayland.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Ubuntu Mate 22.04 ($DESKTOP_SESSION is `mate` and `wmctrl -m` says `Metacity (Marco)`); Every indication is I'm running Wayland (at least "sudo synaptic" says `Probably you're running Synaptic on Wayland with root permission.`). In any case, there is definitely no `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` on my system and `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't contain any lines mentioning Wayland; Any hints on how to permanently disable Wayland in the general case? (i.e. for other desktop managers commonly used with Ubuntu?)

Comment: @MRule, Please run `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`; the output should be either 'wayland' or 'x11'. (I don't think Ubuntu MATE runs Wayland, but I am not sure.) I suggest that you **create an own question** in order to get a good answer (separate from this one).

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi, Thanks for telling that it is important to show how to save the edited file in `nano'. I modify further to show 'key symbols'.