# Wordfast on Ubuntu: Error by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

I am new on Ubuntu (try to switch from Windows).
Now I try to run Wordfast Pro 7.2.0 on Ubuntu.

Running the programm leads to the following error:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f741806b740, pid=8313, tid=8383
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.13+8) (build 11.0.13+8)
> Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.13+8, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
> Problematic frame:
> C  [libX11.so.6+0x2b740]  XInternAtom+0x40

I deinstalled OpenJDK and installed Oracle JDK but still receive the same error.

"java -version" gives:

> Java version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191, mixed mode, sharing)

Could you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, and Ubuntu in general! Which version of Ubuntu are you running? The error that you've experienced is – apologies for the upcoming technobabble – the result of an incompatibility with *some* Wayland sessions. If you are running a version of Ubuntu that uses Wayland, then you'll need to switch it to the older X manager. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1428532/1222991) shows you how to do it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and quick reply!
I run Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I'll try to follow the answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: That solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a missing library:

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```

And restart Wordfast