# Can't use Ctrl-Alt-Fn with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

After moving on to Ubuntu 22.04, I can't use the Ctrl-Alt-Fn set of keys anymore.

Maybe the reason is the input language switch, which works with both

- Ctrl + Alt on both sides
- and superkey + space

However, I see only the second variant in the settings.

How to switch to console only mode?

What happens:

- press Ctrl-Alt-Fn (like F3, or F1, there is no Fn key as such, N is an integer here)
- only language input is changed

*[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6K81LPHJ)*

Consequences:

- Can't change to console
- Can't upgrade NVidia driver
- Can't do data science

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you running? For example Ubuntu Core 22 or Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS, Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS or Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 LTS, Ubuntu Server 22.10 LTS. If Ubuntu Desktop, are you using Xorg or Wayland for the graphics? Please tell us the details, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: thx - I use standard Ubuntu Desktop with default settings.
For more details please share required prompts.
lsb_release => Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: sudodus asked me to join in and see if I can help. Since I will ask you to run commands and ask for the output pasted to a pastebin, I'll do that in an "Answer", That I will "edit" until we get there to a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS with Xorg (x11).

The hotkey combinations <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> ... <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> work for me to get virtual consoles.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> brings me to the log in screen.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> brings me to the graphics desktop.

---

Check if you run Xorg or Wayland with

```
echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"
```

If you run Wayland and want to run Xorg instead, see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428525/how-to-permanetely-disable-wayland/1428532#1428532).

---

In some [laptop] computers you may need to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> (in other words the function key together with <kbd>F3</kbd> ...) to get the desired action.

---

**Edit 1:** I have a somewhat similar system in my Dell Precision laptop with nvidia, but I am not affected by this problem. Differences:

- yours is dist-upgraded from 20.04, mine is installed as 22.04
- yours is newer hardware (and more advanced) than mine
- yours uses an nvidia driver, mine uses nouveau

We also have different sets of installed software (program packages), but I would think one of the listed three differences above might be 'guilty'.

Comment: hi - I've got "echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"" => X11. I do not have Fn

Comment: 1. What computer is it (brand name and model)? 2. Have you installed some special program package (that might cause this problem)? 3. Did you upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu or did you make a fresh installation of 22.04.1 LTS? 4. What language are you using? -- It might be worthwhile to clone from an iso file to make a live Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system on a USB pendrive and check if you have the same problem or if you can get into virtual consoles in that system.

Comment: One way to show what computer and system you have is to run the [system-info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/) by Ubuntu Forums, let it upload the output file to a pastebin and link to the pastebin in your original question.

Comment: added pastebin. It's an upgraded installation on a ZOTAC PC.

Comment: Thanks @Tavi, for the details (in the output of the system-info script) :-) I'm thinking ..., but also trying to involve a person who probably knows more than I about your problem.

Comment: I am the person. Sudodus asked me to help. I added comments above asking for input. Also sent sudodus a PM asking how to format "code" comments here... I'm thinking I am going to have to do that in an "Answer"

Comment: @MAFoElffen, Welcome :-) Use backticks \`code\` --> `code`

Answer (score 1):

You keep saying that your language setting is what may be causing a problem, so I have questions that should show those settings. Please show the following output to new pastebin. Please keep the other pastebin with the 'system-info' report up for me to refer back to):

Code:

```
setxkbmap -query 
xset -q
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources 
locale
localectl status
```

Since you are using Xorg x11, there is an X input diagnostics tool:
In a terminal, enter:

Code:

```
xev
```

That will start a small window on your desktop with a blank box in it. Any Xinput event, such as a keystroke, will dump "what happened" to the terminal session. Separately press the keys [Cntrl], [Alt], and [F3]. Then close the window and copy / paste that output to your pastebin...

I have some other commands that will show/display the current kepmapping of keys and key combinations, once you post the output to those questions...

No response so an explanation of possible causes that sometimes happens and some work-arounds. One cause could be a touchcy video driver. Sometimes this happens to me with some NVidia drivers. Another is some off-brand keyboards.

Two work-arounds for this is on boot, at the Grub2 boot menu, to go to the end of the Linux Boot line that starts with the word 'linux', deleting $vt_handoff (if present) and adding "3" at the end of the line. Then press  to boot into runlevel 3, with will be text / console only (with networking).

Second work around is to change the vtty by commandline via

Code:

```
## -> sudo chvt #
sudo chvt 4 # Will change the vtty session to vtty4
## using 'sudo chvt 7' or [Cntrl][Alt][F7] will return you back to vtty7
```

If fact once you get into a vtty session <F#> will work again, so it is a graphics conflict where it is capturing or remapping keys, kind of thing in the graphics layer...