# ctrl-alt-FN-f7 is active GUI console 22.04 LTS Dell Precision 7560 -- how do I change this?

Tags: shortcut-keys, virtual-console

[Can't use Ctrl-Alt-Fn with Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437291/cant-use-ctrl-alt-fn-with-ubuntu-22-04/1437308#1437308)

In some [laptop] computers you may need to use ctrl + alt +Fn + F3 (in other words the function key together with F3 ...) to get the desired action.

End excerpt.

New installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS current downloaded installation on a Dell Precision 7560 with a new SSD, no Dell pre-installed Ubuntu and no MS Win to dual boot or overwrite.  The above ctrl + alt + Fn + F3 sequence works to display virtual console F3.  However, F1 and F2 are not login and current GUI window manager screens/consoles that are on a different screens than that to which I am accustomed.  Is this configurable?  If so, specific files/commands and exact syntax would be most appreciated. Is there a mechanism NOT to require the three keys (ctrl + alt + Fn) but just crtl + alt, again configurable?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000189154/precision-7560-keyboard-function-guide all you should have to do is to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> keys together to enable or disable the Fn-key lock so that you shouldn't have to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> combination to make the F# key to work.