# How to disable Wayland on multiple users

Tags: users, gdm, wayland, remote-access, teamviewer

I am attempting to disable Wayland on 2 users at the same time on my machine so I could remote connect using TeamViewer.

I tried setting `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` to `WaylandEnable=false` on both users, but whenever I use `$ sudo systemctl restart gdm3` on user 1, then Wayland is de facto re-enabled on user 2, vice versa.

I want to permanently disable Wayland globally, is there something I am missing out on?

Ubuntu Version: 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Proceeding like this is basically the correct way and should work. Did you log out both users and / or restart the system? When coming to the login screen of GDM3, you shouldn't even see the option to use Wayland but only X.org.

Comment: +1, I agree with noisefloor. I think it will work as expected after reboot. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428525/how-to-permanetely-disable-wayland/1428532#1428532) indicates that the method has been verified to work in many computers.