# How to fix auto scrolling without user input

Tags: 22.04

My computer is receiving constant input resulting in it constantly scrolling to the side.

Via xinput --test-xi2 I can see that the wayland mouse device is constantly getting event input no matter if all my mice are turned off or not.

Answer (score 0):

Due to wayland being enabled I could not see what input device was actually making the input. To help with debugging decided to disable wayland and that in turn fixed the problem with no further steps.

I followed the instructions here to disable wayland.

[How to permanetely disable Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428525/how-to-permanetely-disable-wayland)