# The screen of my old Lenovo Yoga doesn’t works

Tags: drivers, lenovo, laptop, screen, 23.10

The screen of my old Lenovo Yoga doesn’t works, I installed Ubuntu 23.10.1 with a secondary monitor.
The strange part is that all the other things like Bluetooth, WiFi and even the touch screen are working.

Here is the link of the specs of the laptop: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/es/es/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-300-11iby/

How can I make it works?

```
lswh -c display
*-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       nombre lógico: /dev/fb0
       versión: 0e
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuración: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1200
       recursos: irq:96 memoria:d0000000-d03fffff memoria:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:2050(size=8) memoria:c0000-dffff
```

I have two screens, the laptop screen and the external one.

In safe graphics mode the screen works but not properly.
[image]

The screen is stretched and the external screen doesn't work

Comment: The posts lacks of a question. Please edit your post and add a question.

Comment: Have you checked "additional drivers"?

Comment: Yes, and it can’t be founded automatically.

Comment: `lshw -c display`?

Comment: @DanielT Editted

Comment: Is the screen detected in Display Settings?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No

Comment: If you are on wayland, try switching to X11 at the login screen. Likewise for X11. The problem here is that somehow the drivers for the Intel GPU are not detecting the laptop screen

Comment: Also, since this is a very lightweight laptop, try Xubuntu 22.04 LTS instead of regular Ubuntu (which demands a lot more resource)

Comment: Here is how to switch to X11 instead of Wayland https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489253/how-can-i-log-into-an-x-session-on-23-10, which @DanielT suggested

Comment: I edited the custom.conf file following the steps in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489253/how-can-i-log-into-an-x-session-on-23-10. After rebooting, nothing has changed; only the external screen works.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have installed Linux Mint instead of Ubuntu, now it works correctly. Thanks for all!