# Moving any window out of Firefox crashes the system

Tags: firefox, snap, crash, 23.04

Using the latest Firefox (112.0.2 (64-bit (snap) with the latest Ubuntu (23.04). Moving any window out of Firefox (for example a browser tab or any downloads) crashes the desktop. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: try running firefox from a terminal and see what errors you get, then post them here

Comment: System crashes before terminal updates. System logs threw these errors, but I'm not sure if they're related:
`Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-166244.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.`
`Failed to start app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dreport\x2don\x2dupgrade-166587.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.`
`Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-166246.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.`

Comment: Does this happen not only in an installed system but also in a *live* system (booted from the USB drive with Ubuntu from the iso file)? Are you running Wayland or X? Check with the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`; What computer and what graphics chip/card is it (brand name and model)?

Comment: Running Wayland with an AMD 6500XT

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a new and powerful graphics card. There might be problems with Wayland. I suggest that you try running X instead. See for example [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406844/ubuntu-22-04-fresh-installation-firefox-will-no-load/1406857#1406857)

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Ever since upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 this started happening. I'm running on wayland and have multiple screens attached which might be contributing to this

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem.  Moving to the snap version stopped the desktop crashing, but firefox itself now simply hangs in tab forever on many pages.  I posted on the Mozilla support site as well, they aslo suspected Wayland, but it happens on X11 for me as well.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1414446

Comment: @JohnT also https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1414353

Answer (score 1):

It happens also for mi in wayland,
Firefox snap for ubuntu 23.04
113.0.2 (64-bit)

When I try to move any tab outside firefox it cashed immediately the entire session.

Comment: I update the snap package (sudo snap refresh firefox) and now it works as expected.

Comment: As pointed out by @guest, upgrading the Firefox snap solved the problem. I'm at 114.0.1-1 now and the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: I see the same problem on 115.0.1