# Can't install old nVidia drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, freeze, nvidia-geforce

I often get freezes, and the only fix is rebooting (often happens if I leave pc, or lock the screen), also sometimes get visual artifacts on my screen.

My graphics card is **NVIDIA GeForce9600 GSO** (prob 2008). (ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

I tried installing drivers, but `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices" only suggested me "nvidia-340" which is not installable (because of dependencies) (I tried a few other methods to install the drivers).

I'm not sure if source of the problem is the graphics card the first place.

1. Can I install nVidia drivers at all?
2. Can it be something else? (pc is old and cheap)

Comment: It is better to use `nouveau` for this card. You won't get any benefits from installing drivers, but it may be a problem.

Comment: You need to use kernel 5.4 to be able to install nvidia-340. Here is a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04/1365644#1365644.